# Identification of a circuit element

Tags: identification, latch, symbol

Here is the image:

[image: Triangle with bubble on the hypotenuse side.]

What does the triangle with a bubble on one of its sides represent?

Comment: In general, "bubble" means a negative logic input (or inversion of output).

Comment: It's a bit of a weird circuit, since normally the behavior of a D latch is undefined for a Z input. Where does this come from?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this for size: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86803/circuit-schematic-symbol-for-buffer-with-control-input). Here's a truth table and picture: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/signal-address).